# Getting data into Word from Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I have an access database filled with informations such as name description date ecc. 
Then I have a word document, that I need to fill. 
The goal would be being able to query the DB from within the Word document passing as an argument a word (the selected word for example) and getting the results shown somehow. They are meant to be a reference for deciding the price to apply from historical data.
Is there a way to do this or shall I give up? I have some skills in VBA, Excel and Acces, but almost none when it comes to Word.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Word uses VBA too. It should be possible to do what you want do. Take a look at programming in Word and see how you get on.

Comment: Without VBA: would you be OK with database fields? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Field-codes-Database-field-04398159-a2c9-463f-bb59-558a87badcbc?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US